# Why was the flow of this sentence changed?

Tags: word-order

One editor of mine changed the noun order in a sentence of my article. It seems minor, but I would like to figure out the reason. Is it just because the revision makes the sentence flow sound better? Like, we had better put a word of more vowels at the end of a sentence instead of the middle?

Below please see the change. Please kindly advise. Thanks!

### Original Version:

> “The path of Chinese discipline to internationalisation is **heavy and long**!”

### Revised Version:

> “The path of Chinese discipline to internationalisation is **long and heavy**!”

Comment: This question seems related to your previous question, since we could also compare "heavy long path" with "long heavy path".  The latter sounds better to me.  (I recall once trying to find what principles determine what seems the most natural order in  such cases.  Couldn't figure it out.)

Comment: "Long and heavy" flows better, plus it tends to put more emphasis on the "long" aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This word order is a cultural convention (not a requirement of logic). It therefore sounds more "natural" to native speakers.

There is a [word order](https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/adjectiveorder.html) for English adjectives:

> Opinion     Size    Age     Shape   Colour  Material    Origin  Purpose

The problem: *Weight* does not fit in here. The principle might be the same, i.e. a convention that says that *size* comes before *weight*. I asked this [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/521961/weight-in-opinion-size-age-shape-colour-material-origin-purpose?noredirect=1#comment1269678_521961).

Too complicate things more, there is [another rule](http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20160908-the-language-rules-we-know-but-dont-know-we-know) that exempts the above rule but this happens quite seldom (e.g. it's *Big Bad Wolf*, not *Bad Big Wolf*). It requires the order of vowels to be ⟨i⟩, ⟨a⟩, ⟨o⟩ (or in IPA: /ɪ/, /æ/, /ɔ/. For instance:

> ding, dang, dong

The first vowel in *h**ea**vy*, /ɛ/, is close to /æ/. So my first thought was that "long and heavy" should comply with this rule. But it does not. This might have several reasons. Firstly, it's not an instance of [reduplication](http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/a-hotchpotch-of-reduplication). Secondly, the words are separated by *and*.

Comment: Why is "big bad" more idiomatic than "bad big"? I note (Google NGrams) that "big happy" prevails over "happy big", too. But is it really the vowels? "Big ugly" prevails over "ugly big". Perhaps it's just something about "big" when used with an "opinion" adjective?

Comment: The linked article also gives the example of *Little Red Riding Hood*.

Comment: The 'Royal Order' applies only to prenominal chains, to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to explain.  To a native speaker it just sounds more correct.  Long and hard.  Long and arduous.  We tend to put the long first because long is not necessarily bad, but the second part is. That way the sentence builds to a conclusion.